# AVR не передает данные по UART

Tags: c, avr, atmel-studio, uart

Когда я работал в Arduino, то пользовался Serial.begin(9600). Сейчас нужно реализовать минимальный UART на AVR
Привожу код инициализации из AVR Studio 7:

```
 #include <avr/io.h>

 #define F_CPU 8000000 //8 MHz


int main(void)
{

  UBRRH = 0;
  UBRRL = 51; //здесь точно подбираю из http://wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php

  UCSRA = 0b00000000;
  UCSRB = 0b00011000;
  UCSRC = 0b10000110;


  while(1)
  {
    UDR = 0x44; //посылаю число 44
  }
}
```

Уже 3 рабочий день решаю эту задачу, поэтому из учебников взял самый минимум - только чтобы посылки из AVR шли. Зашиваю с фьюзом 8 МГц (в записи и PC проблем быть не должно - помогают)

Comment: Учтите, что есть фьюз CKDIV8, который по умолчанию активен и делит тактовую частоту на 8.

Используйте стандартные константы вместо битовых масок - тогда ваш код можно будет разобрать без залезания в даташит. Я, например, тратить на это время не хочу.

Comment: UCSRA = 0;
UCSRB  = 24 (0x18);
UCSRC = 134 (0x86);

Comment: для каждого бита конфигурационных решистров контроллера существуют именованные константы. Нужно использовать их, а не битовые маски, тогда код можно будет читать.

Посмотрите уже пример http://www.appelsiini.net/2011/simple-usart-with-avr-libc

Answer (score 0):

При использовании UART в AVR берите тактирование от кварца. Встроенный RC генератор имеет низкую точность для UART (тем более, что, по крайней мере для ATMega162, частота встроенного RC генератора оговаривается в даташите для напряжения 3В при комнатной температуре.